# This value is not a function and cannot be applied - F#

Tags: f#

```
// Learn more about F# at http://fsharp.org
// See the 'F# Tutorial' project for more help.

open System

let highLowGame () = 
    let rng = new Random()
    let secretNumber = rng.Next() % 100 + 1

    let rec highLowGameStep () = 
        printfn "Guess the secret number: " 
        let guessStr = Console.ReadLine()
        let guess = Int32.Parse(guessStr)

        match guess with
        | _ when guess > secretNumber
            -> (printfn "The secret number is lower")
                highLowGameStep ()
        | _ when guess = secretNumber
            -> (printfn "You've guessed correctly!")
                ()
        | _ when guess < secretNumber
            -> (printfn "The secret number is higher")
                highLowGameStep ()

    highLowGameStep ()

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    printfn "%A" argv
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

I've checked this code like a thousand times and I get a warning saying g`uess is incomplete on pattern matching` which is definitely impossible... and I also get an error saying the `value is not a function and cannot be applied.`

I copied this straight out of a book so I don't get how this is not compiling?!

Comment: This is example code from a book?!? It crashes on invalid user input, has a line that does nothing, causes a compiler warning, has useless parentheses and weird formatting for no benefit, abuses wildcard pattern matching in place of `if-then-elif`, and creates a non-disposable type with `new`. Even if the whitespace should be correct in the original, might I suggest getting a different book?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add semicolons after the `printfn` statements, it will work. I believe the reason it hadn't been compiling is because you were trying to return a `printfn` and another function (highLowGameStep) from your match.

Comment: vcsjones said it was whitespace and that worked but then I tried your solution it worked too! Gah, F# is confusing

Comment: @LukeXu both are acceptable ways to fix it. Adding semicolons fixes the problem of the compiler not being able to properly separate statements. Adding the semicolon is an explicit way of doing so.

Comment: Hahaha.. yeah functional programming is definitely very interesting. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Try Haskell; then your view on F# will change.

Comment: @GuyCoder I actually started in Haskell so I could get the "pure" functional approach. I'm trying to learn F# now because there's more jobs in F#.

Answer (score 6):

The white space on the pattern match is wrong. It should be something like this:

```
match guess with
| _ when guess > secretNumber ->
        (printfn "The secret number is lower")
        highLowGameStep ()
| _ when guess = secretNumber ->
        (printfn "You've guessed correctly!")
        ()
| _ when guess < secretNumber ->
        (printfn "The secret number is higher")
        highLowGameStep ()
```

That fixes the compilation error. As for the warning, the compiler is making a best guess, but it isn't able to determine that all cases are actually covered. If you want to fix the warning, you can add another case:

```
| _ -> invalidOp("Invalid input")
```

Comment: What in the world... how is my white space wrong. You're right... I changed it from spaces to tabs and it seemed to work

Comment: @LukeXu I specifically meant the `->`, notice they are on the top line. Using tabs in F# can be tricky.